# Spring Cloud Gateway unable to find microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, api-gateway

I have setup 3 microservices using springboot and an api gateway using SpringBoot.
The problem is when I configured the gateway I got "404: Path not found" error. I double checked everything and the services were working fine and were registered in the eureka server.

I tried using lower-case and upper-case for naming the services, restarted the discovery-client, searched on stack-overflow for similar problems but none of them worked.

My pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hunterx</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api-gateway</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My application.properties file for api-gateway service

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
spring.application.name=api-gateway

spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true

logging.level=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionLocator = INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.gateway=TRACE

#Product Service Route
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=product-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://product-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/api/product

#Order Service Route
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=order-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://order-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/api/order
```

Answer (score 2):

When I downloaded the Spring Cloud Gateway library from Spring Initializer, it generated the maven file for `<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc</artifactId>`. After going through a LOT of videos and projects I realised it is actually `<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>`. It's working fine now.

Comment: Your solution really helped me. I faced similar issue that you mentioned. Thanks man :)